# Can I remove a BTRFS device online if that device is the one that is mounted?

Tags: linux, raid, btrfs

As described [here](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Removing_devices), BTRFS devices can be removed from an array using:

> `btrfs device delete /dev/sdc /mnt`

I have a BTRFS RAID 1 array made up of 3 devices. One of devices is failing and I want to remove it from the array (I have plenty of space so I'm just going to remove it instead of replacing it). However, the device I want to remove is the one shown in the output of `df`.

Can I remove the device online in this case? Or should I change the mount to target one of the other devices in the array and then remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried mounting a different device by targeting its [World Wide Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name), but `df` still showed the previous device, so I went for the delete and once the device had been removed from the BTRFS array the output of `df` changed.

So my guess is that `df` picks the first device in the array in lexicographical order.